# How to search and replace exact character and number using re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex in python to search for `"p1"` in `"p1 p2 p3 p10 p11 p12"` and replace it with `"hi"`

Below is my Python Code:

```
import re

x = "p1 p2 p3 p10 p11 p12"
data = "p1"
y = re.sub(data,'hi',x)
print (y)
```

Current output → `hi p2 p3 hi0 hi1 hi2`.
Desired output → `hi p2 p3 p10 p11 p12`.

Please help me understand why I am not getting my desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a word break.  Regular expressions should use raw strings so you don't have to escape the backslashes.

```
import re

x = "p1 p2 p3 p1 p10 p11 p12 p1"
data = "p1"
y = re.sub(r'\b' + data + r'\b','hi',x)
print (y)
```

Output:

```
hi p2 p3 hi p10 p11 p12 hi
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot edit 'data' variable in my actual code. Hadus solution has worked for me.

Comment: @LOKENDRASINGHSHEKHAWAT Use `r'\b' + data + r'\b'` then.  What if `p1` is at the end of the string and it doesn't have a space?  `\b` matches a work break (beginning of string, end of string, etc.).

Comment: I just face these problem this morning, and you are right, when 'p1' is at the end of the string, then the +"  " doesn't work for me. Your solution is working perfectly. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is search for not `data` but `data+" "`.

```
import re

x = "p1 p2 p3 p10 p11 p12"

data = "p1"

y = re.sub(data+" ", "hi"+" ", x)

# to replace at the end too:
if x[-len(data):] == data:
    y = y[:-len(data)] + "hi"

print (y) # hi p2 p3 p10 p11 p12
```

You were replacing "p1" in the string what meant that the first part of "p11" was replaced too. You should have been looking for "p1 " that way you would not replace "p11". But now that we are replacing something with space at the end of it, we need to make the inserted string also have space at the end. Otherwise, we would be removing spaces.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I replace the 'data' with data+" ".  Now the output, I am getting is - hip2 p3 p10 p11 p12. There is no space between hi and p2.

Comment: Kudos to you, This has worked smoothly. if possible, Can you please explain me, what basically this +" " has done and what was wrong in my code.

Comment: `string+another_string` just concatenates them. In your case, we have `data+" "` so we append a space to whatever is in data. And the same thing with "hi". I would rather change "hi" to "hi " though because it would be more clear.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the data match was at the end of the string.

Comment: Hi Hadus, your solution did work for me and thanks for the explanation, I got it now but Mark is right, when 'data' is at the end of the string then it is not replacing. I appreciate both of your help.