# How to exactly match a word and then replace in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

1. Have a list which contains strings etc. as shown below

   ```
   strpool = ['fruit,apple:3', '', '[1,abcd, ['fruit,apple'], ['1,kdlld', apple,taste]]']
   ```
2. Wanted to search exactly for the word 'apple' and replace with 'apple:3'
3. I tried the below code,

   ```
   print str(strpool).replace("apple","apple:3")
   print (re.sub(r"\bapple\b","apple:3",str(strpool)))
   ```
4. But its replacing even the apple:3  as well into apple:3:3 , not just the string apple.
5. Thought apple:3 would be considered as a string and that doesn't get changed.

Update:
How can I exactly match a string name without any other components attached to it and replace all of them inside a list ?

Tried re.sub but for that need to convert the list to string, instead is there any other way ?

Comment: `\b` matches a word boundary. There's a word boundary between `apple` and `:` in the original `apple:3`, so it matches.

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437984/how-to-search-and-replace-exact-character-and-number-using-re-sub

Comment: So you want to match a word UNLESS it's already followed by `:`, is that it? Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: @Barmar: True I just wanted to match the exact word, and not with the ones which is followed by string and any other character like : or , or etc.. Negative lookahead ? but then I wanted to convert all the strings inside the list.

Comment: What do you mean by an exact word? If you have `apple,fruit`, isn't `apple` an exact word? Why is it an exact word in `fruit,apple` but not an exact word in `apple,fruit`?

Comment: @Barmar Oh when I meant exact word, was referring to just apple and not like apple:3 or apple,3 or apple!3 , something like that inside a list.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a word unless it's followed by `:`.

```
print(re.sub(r'\bapple\b(?!:)', 'apple:3', str(strpool))
```